# Java - cannot connect to server - connection refused

Tags: java, android, connection, nio

I am using the java.nio package to create a TCP client-server connection between two android devices.
Here is what the client does:

```
SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(gameAddr, 8001));
```

Here is what the server does:

```
try 
        {
            tokenizer = new FixedSeparatorMessageTokenizer(Strings.DELIMITER, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
            sChan = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            InetSocketAddress iaddr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8001);

            sChan.configureBlocking(false);
            sChan.socket().bind(iaddr);

            sChan.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            sockets = new Vector<SocketChannel>();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<SelectionKey> it;

        try {
            while (selector.isOpen()) 
            {

                selector.select();

                it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) 
                {
                    SelectionKey key = it.next();

                    it.remove();
                    if (!key.isValid()) 
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (key.isConnectable()) 
                    {
                        SocketChannel ssc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        if (ssc.isConnectionPending()) ssc.finishConnect();
                    }

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) 
                    {
                        ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                        SocketChannel newClient = ssc.accept();

                        newClient.configureBlocking(false);
                        newClient.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        sockets.add(newClient);

                        System.out.println("Connection from " + newClient.socket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                    }

                    if (key.isReadable()) {
                        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(sc.socket().getSendBufferSize());

                        System.out.println("Data from " + sc.socket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

                        if (sc.read(data) == -1) //is this a socket close?
                        {

                            continue;
                        }

                        data.flip();
                        tokenizer.addBytes(data);
                        while(tokenizer.hasMessage())
                        {
                            ParsedMessage pm = new ParsedMessage(tokenizer.nextMessage());
                            pm.setAttachment(sc);
                            synchronized(Q) { Q.add(pm); }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

They both are using the same port 8001 (I tried different ports) and they are in the same LAN because UDP packets actually make it from one device to the other. What can be the problem?

Comment: try using "localhost" as hostname or address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connection refused" means that the connection attempt from the client reached the server (or *a* server), but there was nothing accepting connections at the specified IP address and port. Since you are using port 8001 in both cases, the simplest explanation is that either your server or your client aren't using the correct IP address to communicate with the other end.

You're using this line to create the server socket:

```
InetSocketAddress iaddr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8001);
```

the simplest explanation is that `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` isn't returning the same IP address that the client is using.

Comment: it seems that InetAddress.getLocalHost() actually returns the loopback address 127.0.0.1. Does this mean that the server is only accepting connections from its own device?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The server would only receive connections from clients that specified 127.0.0.1 as the target address. And since it's the loopback address, the client would have to be on the same host as the server.